# Scheme sum-of-squares test

Tags: testing, scheme, sum

I wrote a sum-of-squares function to test if a number n could be written as the sum of two squares. My code is as follows:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (sum-of-squares n)
 (define (sum-of-squares-h k)
    (cond ((= k n) #f)
       ((= n (+ (square(floor(sqrt k)))(square(floor(sqrt(- n k))))))#t)
                (sum-of-squares-h (+ k 1))))
    (sum-of-squares-h 1))
```

When I test things such as :

```
(sum-of-squares 1)
(sum-of-squares 2)
(sum-of-squares 4)
(sum-of-squares 8)
(sum-of-squares 10)
```

My output is:

```
#f
#t
2
2
#t
```

Where did I go wrong/ what can I do to fix this? I have seen other ways to go about doing this problem, but if someone could help me by using what I already have that would be great. I am not too familiar with the floor function so I may have used it incorrectly.

## EDIT - code with a few tweaks

```
 (define (square x) (* x x))
  (define (sum-of-squares n)
   (define (sum-of-squares-h k)
     (cond ((= k n) #f)
           ((< n 4) #f)
           ((= n (+ (square(floor(sqrt k)))(square(floor(sqrt(- n k))))))#t)
                 (sum-of-squares-h (+ k 1))))
     (sum-of-squares-h 1))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the formula you're using to determine if a number if the sum of two squares, can you post a link to the source?

Comment: I don't have a link... my logic may be flawed. How can I return "k" and "(-n k)" when sum-of-squares-h returns true to see if I am getting correct values?

Comment: In the code, put a `(display (list k (- n k)))` at the exact point before `#t` is being returned, so you can check the result. Or use a debugger ;)

Comment: It returns (4 4)#t for the test of 8 and (1 9)#t for the test of 10. This is just two examples, but the others work as well. Since 4 4 1 and 9 are all perfect squares this works as intended :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `else` part in the last condition:

```
(define (sum-of-squares n)
  (define (sum-of-squares-h k)
    (cond ((= k n)
           #f)
          ((= n (+ (square (floor (sqrt k)))
                   (square (floor (sqrt (- n k))))))
           #t)
          (else
           (sum-of-squares-h (+ k 1)))))
  (sum-of-squares-h 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function that finds all the ways that a number *n* can be written as the sum of squares:

```
(define (squares n)
  (let loop ((x (isqrt n)) (y 0) (zs '()))
    (cond ((< x y) zs)
          ((< (+ (* x x) (* y y)) n) (loop x (+ y 1) zs))
          ((< n (+ (* x x) (* y y))) (loop (- x 1) y zs))
          (else (loop (- x 1) (+ y 1) (cons (list x y) zs))))))
```

The algorithm is from Dijkstra: *x* sweeps downward from the square root of *n* while *y* sweeps upward from zero; recursion stops when *x* and *y* cross. You can read more about it at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/01/05/the-sum-of-two-squares/).